# How can I catch events in the logs of two applications via Python

Tags: python, logging

I have a program that works in 2 copies of the game. They both write logs to two different files under two different accounts.
How can I read these logs in real time and as soon as both accounts have the message "match_id:" in a certain line and the same id perform actions?
I could not find anything similar, can you tell me how I can implement this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You need [logging.Handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler). Override the `emit(record)` function to detect when a specific output happens. Note that you may need `inspect.currentframe()` to get the function that is currently running.